# Compass Failed error on compiling SASS via Gulp

Tags: gulp, compass-sass, compass

Hy everyone.

I'm fighting with this issue during old project CSS recompiling via Gulp. It's using Compass for SASS. Here the issue:

> LoadError on line ["179"] of /Users/lucacattide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.3/lib/compass/configuration/data.rb: cannot load such file -- compass/import-once/activate
>   Run with --trace to see the full backtrace
>   events.js:173
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>         ^
>   Error: Compass failed

I tried many times - with no results - in:

- Reinstall Ruby with RVM (from version 2.1 to 2.6);
- Reinstall SASS (v. 3.3);
- Reinstall Compass with `compass-import-once gem`;

It's running on OS X 10.13.6.

Any suggestion on this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by proceeding to manually compass installation.

- I updated my stack by reinstalling latest version of Ruby via RVM, then SASS and Compass gems - as many tutorial suggests;
- Next, I deleted all the `.lock` and `vendor/cache` (the Ruby ones) project files
- I updated the `Gemfile` by including these lines:

```
gem 'compass'
gem 'compass-import-once', :require => "compass/import-once/activate"
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.4.1'
gem 'sassc-rails', '>= 2.1.0'
```

- Then I launched
  `bundle install`

On the next gulp default task launch (which were previously configured to run the `gulp-sass` one), everything worked.